# Ubuntu 16.0 poor performance with RAM 2 GB. hangs a lot. What should I do?

Tags: ram

My sytem's specs are:
AMD 2.8 GHz processor
160GB HDD
RAM 2 GB.
I am a window user who wants to start with ubuntu. I have installed Ubuntu 16.0 but it hangs all of a sudden. I don't know the shortcut to kiss the tasks even. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you mean "Ubuntu 16.04"? You should try "Ubuntu 14.04" instead which has much lower RAM requirements.

Comment: If you're having RAM issues in standard Ubuntu I would try lighter variants such as Lubuntu, or even light desktop environments/window managers such as XFCE.

Comment: Yeah, I use Lubntu now. :)